# Laravel new routes return 404, when deploying to Forge

Tags: laravel, laravel-forge

I have deployed new code to my Forge server. This code includes new routes (web, api, with and without auth).I have run `php artisan optimize`, but all the new routes return a 404.
The `php artisan route:list` command display the new routes. I am getting crazy...

Help!?

thanks

Comment: Have you cleared the route cache? `php artisan route:cache` ?

Comment: `php artisan optimize:clear` then again optimize it by `php artisan optimize`

Comment: Please update the questions with routes that are missing, if you have dynamic routes please change the order

Comment: @HassaanAli Yes I did.

Comment: @EsTeAa Not better.

Comment: @localroot I tried with a simple dummy route, added on top of the web routes file. `Route::get('hw', function() { return 'hello world'; });`

Comment: So some of your routes are working and newly added routes are not working right?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Answer (score 1):

OK, someone gave me the solution on Laravel's Slack. I had to relaunch PHP fpm on my Forge server, in order to reset the OPCache.